# Why do E.coli form parallel clusters?

Tags: theoretical-biology, ecoli

Discalimer: I am not a biologist. I am modelling E.Coli growth and in the [Wikipedia gif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escherichia_coli#/media/File:E.coli-colony-growth.gif) one can see observe some groups where the bacteria are one next to each other, oriented at approximately the same angle. I did some simulations and obtained similar results. Is there any reason why this happens?

Answer (score 3):

Cell division happens by division at the middle of the rod, so the result is two daughter cells that are at nearly the same angle. Over time in the absence of agitation moving cells around, this will lead to a groups of cells that have non-independent cell orientations.

For more information, including how people have induced it to do otherwise, see [this paper](https://jb.asm.org/content/196/11/2089).

Answer (score 1):

Bacterial cells prefer to attach with each other in parallel orientation so that they have maximum surface of contact and could form biofilm clusters.

Both physical factors (like Brownian motion, electrostatic interactions, gravity, van der Waals forces and hydrodynamics)  and cellular function in bacterial cells (bacterial motility, production of polysaccharides, and functions of structures in outer membrane) are responsible for this orientation.

(Via: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep29516)